# Why is convnet transfer learning taking so long?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, transfer-learning, convolutional-neural-network, vgg16

I am using transfer learning to train a binary image classification model using keras' pretrained VGG16 model. The code can be found below :

```
training_dir = '/Users/rishabh/Desktop/CyberBoxer/data/train'
validation_dir = '/Users/rishabh/Desktop/CyberBoxer/data/validation'
image_files = glob(training_dir + '/*/*.jpg')
valid_image_files = glob(validation_dir + '/*/*.jpg')
# importing the libraries
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
from keras.applications import VGG16
#from keras.preprocessing import image

IMAGE_SIZE = [64, 64]  # we will keep the image size as (64,64). You 
can increase the size for better results. 

# loading the weights of VGG16 without the top layer. These weights are 
trained on Imagenet dataset.
vgg = VGG16(input_shape = IMAGE_SIZE + [3], weights = 'imagenet', 
include_top = False)  # input_shape = (64,64,3) as required by VGG

# this will exclude the initial layers from training phase as there are 
already been trained.
for layer in vgg.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

x = Flatten()(vgg.output)
#x = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(x)   # we can add a new fully 
connected layer but it will increase the execution time.
x = Dense(num_classes, activation = 'softmax')(x)  # adding the output 
layer with softmax function as this is a multi label classification 
problem.

model = Model(inputs = vgg.input, outputs = x)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input

training_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                                rescale=1./255,   # all pixel values will be between 0 an 1
                                shear_range=0.2, 
                                zoom_range=0.2,
                                horizontal_flip=True,
                                preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255, preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

training_generator = training_datagen.flow_from_directory(training_dir, 
target_size = IMAGE_SIZE, batch_size = 200, class_mode = 'categorical')
validation_generator = 
validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_dir, target_size = 
IMAGE_SIZE, batch_size = 200, class_mode = 'categorical')

training_images = 3717
validation_images = 885

history = model.fit_generator(training_generator,
               steps_per_epoch = 3717,  # this should be equal to total number of images in training set. But to speed up the execution, I am only using 10000 images. Change this for better results. 
               epochs = 1,  # change this for better results
               validation_data = validation_generator,
               validation_steps = 885)  # this should be equal to total number of images in validation set.
```

I am training it on just 3700 images but still a single epoch is taking around 10-12 hours. Is this supposed to happen ? Am I doing anything wrong ? I had to downgrade my keras to 2.1.4 for the code to run so is it something affecteing the learning ?

Comment: How long does it take you to train the same model without transfer learning?

Comment: Are you training using a CPU or GPU?

Comment: @user1825567 If I use a model like a simple CNN it takes around 1 or 2 minutes to train for a single epoch

Comment: @Oxbowerce I am using my local machine right now so I guess it'll be using CPU only. But even in such a case, for a dataset of only 3700, is a single epoch in transfer learning bound to take so much time ?

Comment: In that case your first two questions can be answered right away. No, this isn't supposed to happen and yes you are doing something wrong. Let's wait for someone to point out the bug for you.

Comment: Try w/o **steps_per_epoch** parm. I hope it's not going in an infinite loop. Ideally, you should get  _WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training_. Since 3717 steps are called with a batch of 200.

Answer (score 1):

It might have to do with `ImageDataGenerator`. Data augmentation can be computational expensive. Remove that code and see if the model trains faster.